# How to do 301 redirect in rails routes if parameter in upper case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, routes, http-status-code-301, actioncontroller

How can I do 301 redirect in routes.rb based on a condition that if certain parameter is in upper case thn redirect to lower case URL.

I know i can make URLs case insensitive but thats not what I want.

for example if users hits this URL
/Company/XYZ or /company/Xyz

he should be redirected to 
/company/xyz

Is this even possible with 301 redirects or do I have to use 302 redirects.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't how how to do this in `routes.rb`, but I'm not sure that's the right place for it either.  I'd put it into the controller action.  Something like:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    company_id = params[:id]
    if company_id =~ /\A[[:upper:]]+\z/
      redirect_to company_path(company_id.downcase), status: :moved_permanently
    end
    # Handle normal process flow.
  end

end
```

If you wanted to, you could setup a `before_filter` and handle this more generically for all the cases where a single record is accessed (`show`, `edit`, `update`).  You could even put a filter into `ApplicationController` if you wanted to do this for all models.

Comment: I have no skills in regexps, so what if I have url like this:
`/company/Xyz-xYz-xyz` and so on

Comment: If you want to redirect when the id contains *any* uppercase letters, you can use `/[[:upper:]]/`.

Comment: Is making such before filters in app controller a good practice?